# Why does there appear to be different types of Pearson's autocorrelation?

Tags: correlation, autocorrelation, pearson-r

If you Google Images "auto-correlation", you will find many formulae of this form (from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57185_01/CBREG/ch06s03s03s03.html)):-

[image: oracle]

I've implemented this and so with a sequence { 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72 }, $r_k = 0.625$ for a lag of $k=1$. That matches exactly with [this](https://www.easycalculation.com/statistics/autocorrelation.php) online calculator, and [this](https://scicoding.com/4-ways-of-calculating-autocorrelation-in-python/) demo (if you use their example sequence instead). So my coding is perfect :-)

Yet. LibreOffice Calc tells me the correlation is 1.0.  So does Python's Pandas. And the classic interpretation of Pearson is that two monotonic (by +1) sequences should have a value of +1.0.

So why the difference please?

Comment: Could it be that they show you the autocorrelation at lag 0?

Comment: I think the answer is here: [What's the difference between pandas ACF and statsmodel ACF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36038927/whats-the-difference-between-pandas-acf-and-statsmodel-acf). Check the comparison between `autocorr` and `acf`.

Comment: @T.E.G. Mmm, I'll check.  But a counter comment - in the classic chart of correlation you see everywhere, does the line have to be exactly @ 45 degrees for rk = 1?

Answer (score 2):

Given a finite time series $\{y_1, \ldots, y_n\}$, the usual definition for the sample autocovariance at lag $k$ is
$$
\hat{\gamma}_k = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{t=k+1}^n (y_t - \bar{y})(y_{t-k} - \bar{y})\,.
$$
Notice that we're dividing by $n$ even though there are only $n-k$ terms in the sum. The sample autocorrelation at lag $k$ is then $\hat{\rho}_k =\hat{\gamma}_k /\hat{\gamma}_0$, so the $1/n$ cancels out and you obtain the formula in your post. The `stats::acf` function in R uses the same convention.

If in your definition of $\hat{\gamma}_k$ you divide by $n-k$ instead of $n$ (which is what `pandas.Series.autocorr` does), you get $\hat{\rho}_1=1$ instead.

The difference is negligible for long time series (large $n$), but not for small $n$.